# How to truncate a string in elixir?

Tags: elixir

I'm working with slugs for elixir, the idea is: I have a string with `[a-zA-Z0-9]` words separated by hyphens. Like:

```
string = "another-long-string-to-be-truncated-and-much-text-here"
```

I want to be ensure that max string length equals to 30, but I also want to be sure that words aren't cut by half on reaching maximum length. So that first 30 symbols of `string` are `another-long-string-to-be-trun` but I want to have `another-long-string-to-be` with word `truncated` to be removed completely. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9):

First of all, **if you don't care about performance at all**, you can relay all the work to the regex:

`~r/\A(.{0,30})(?:-|\Z)/`

I assume it will be the shortest solution, but not efficient:

```
iex(28)> string
"another-long-string-to-be-truncated-and-much-text-here"
iex(29)> string2
"another-long-string-to-be-cool-about-that"

iex(30)> Regex.run(~r/\A(.{0,30})(?:-|\Z)/, string) |> List.last() 
"another-long-string-to-be"

iex(31)> Regex.run(~r/\A(.{0,30})(?:-|\Z)/, string2) |> List.last()
"another-long-string-to-be-cool"
```

### Efficient solution

But if you do care about performance and memory, then I suggest this:

```
defmodule CoolSlugHelper do
  def slug(input, length \\ 30) do
    length_minus_1 = length - 1

    case input do
      # if the substring ends with "-"
      # i. e. "abc-def-ghi", 8 or "abc-def-", 8 -> "abc-def"
      <<result::binary-size(length_minus_1), "-", _::binary>> -> result

      # if the next char after the substring is "-"
      # i. e. "abc-def-ghi", 7 or "abc-def-", 7 -> "abc-def"
      <<result::binary-size(length), "-", _::binary>> -> result

      # if it is the exact string. i. e. "abc-def", 7 -> "abc-def"
      <<_::binary-size(length)>> -> input

      # return an empty string if we reached the beginnig of the string
      _ when length <= 1 -> ""

      # otherwise look into shorter substring
      _ -> slug(input, length_minus_1)
    end
  end
end
```

It does not collect the resulting string char-by-char. Instead, it looks for the correct substring starting from the desired length down to 1. That's how it becomes efficient in terms of memory and speed.

We need this `length_minus_1` variable because we cannot use expressions in the `binary-size` binary pattern matching.

Here is the benchmark of all the proposed solutions as of Dec 22nd, 2018:

(Simple Regex is the `~r/\A(.{0,30})(?:-|\Z)/` regex above)

```
Name                     ips        average  deviation         median         99th %
CoolSlugHelper      352.14 K        2.84 μs  ±1184.93%           2 μs           8 μs
SlugHelper           70.98 K       14.09 μs   ±170.20%          10 μs          87 μs
Simple Regex         33.14 K       30.17 μs   ±942.90%          21 μs         126 μs
Truncation           11.56 K       86.51 μs    ±84.81%          62 μs         299 μs

Comparison: 
CoolSlugHelper      352.14 K
SlugHelper           70.98 K - 4.96x slower
Simple Regex         33.14 K - 10.63x slower
Truncation           11.56 K - 30.46x slower

Memory usage statistics:

Name              Memory usage
CoolSlugHelper         2.30 KB
SlugHelper            12.94 KB - 5.61x memory usage
Simple Regex          20.16 KB - 8.75x memory usage
Truncation            35.36 KB - 15.34x memory usage
```

Comment: Indeed, I have re-linked “better answer reference” from the most upvoted answer to this one. Also I am surprised and frustrated that `binary-size` is _as_ faster than char-by-char recursion.

Answer (score 8):

**UPD 12/2018** Yuri Golobokov posted the better solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53894692/2035262), I’d suggest to use it instead of the below.

---

The simplest approach would be:

```
"another-long-string-to-be-truncated-and-much-text-here"
|> String.slice(0..29) 
|> String.replace(~r{-[^-]*$}, "")
#⇒ "another-long-string-to-be"
```

There is one glitch with it: if the hyphen is exactly on position 31, the last term will be removed. To avoid this, one might explicitly check fot the condition above:

```
str = "another-long-string-to-be-truncated-and-much-text-here"
case str |> String.at(30) do                                      
  "-" -> str |> String.slice(0..29)                                  
  _   -> str |> String.slice(0..29) |> String.replace(~r{-[^-]*$}, "")
end                                                               
#⇒ "another-long-string-to-be"
```

or:

```
orig = "another-long-string-to-be-cool-cated-and-much-text-here"
str = orig |> String.slice(0..29) 
unless String.at(orig, 30) == "-", do: str = str |> String.replace(~r{-[^-]*$}, "")
str
#⇒ "another-long-string-to-be-cool"
```

Comment: There is a subtle bug here: if the original string contains a single word that is longer than 30 characters, the original word is returned. This results in a string longer than 30 chars, I suppose it should return an empty string instead.

Comment: @PatrickOscity it currently returns this word truncated to 30 codepoints. Returning an empty string _as a slug_ sounds like an ...uhm poor design to me.

Comment: @mudasobwa Your code returns `"another-long-string-to-be-tru-"` for this input `"another-long-string-to-be-tru-n"`. I guess the regular expression has to be the following: `[-[^-]*]$`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it recursively..

```
defmodule Truncation do
  def truncate_words_to(str, max) do
    length = String.length(str)
    words? = Regex.match?(~r{-}, str)
    cond do
      length <= max -> str
      words?        -> truncate_words_to(String.replace(str, ~r{-[^-]*$}, ""),
                                         max)
      true          -> String.slice(str, 0..(max-1))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `cond` makes no sense since `true` condition is perfectly applicable when `length <= max`. One might use `if` there.

Comment: It's true that `String.slice` would work if the string is already shorter than `max`, but we still need the separate `length <= max` check to avoid chopping a word off unnecessarily. So we still have three different cases: string is already short enough, string is too long and contains a hyphen, or string is too long and doesn't contain a hyphen.

Comment: Ah, yes, got it, sorry. The question now is what if the `max`th symbol is a hyphen?

Comment: Good point.  Changed the quantifier on the regex so that a final hyphen gets chopped off. (Or a final series of hyphens, albeit at the cost of a separate recursion per hyphen.)

Comment: Upvoted, because it’s the most natural way to solve this kind of task, even though it looks a bit overdesigned when we have elixir `String` helpers.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on @mudasobwa answer, but I decided to simplify it a lot

```
"another-long-string-to-be-truncated-and-much-text-here"
|> String.slice(0..29)
|> String.split("-")
|> Enum.slice(0..-2)
|> Enum.join("-")
```

That's it!

Comment: This is nonsense. It a) returns a list, b) fails on the case when 31st codepoint in the string is a hyphen and c) implies redundant coercion to/from a list.

Comment: @mudasobwa a) you're correct I forgot about join b)  I have no experienced a failure c) but it's easy to read instead

Comment: b) you had, but you like were unable to understand it. Try it on `"another-long-string-to-be-cool-cated-and-much-text-here"`. Your code produces `"another-long-string-to-be`", while the correct result is `"another-long-string-to-be-cool"`. I have described this corner case in the last para of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question still gets hits from search engines, I’d post *the proper, fast, elixirish* solution to accomplish this task.

```rb
defmodule SlugHelper do
  def slug(input, length \\ 30, acc \\ {"", ""})
  def slug("", _, {_, result}), do: result
  def slug(_, 0, {_, result}), do: result
  def slug(<<"-", _::binary>>, 1, {acc, result}), do: result
  def slug(<<"-", rest::binary>>, length, {acc, ""}), do:
    slug(rest, length - 1, {"", acc})
  def slug(<<"-", rest::binary>>, length, {acc, result}), do:
    slug(rest, length - 1, {"", result <> "-" <> acc})
  def slug(<<chr::binary-size(1), rest::binary>>, length, {acc, result}),
    do: slug(rest, length - 1, {acc <> chr, result})
end

string = "another-long-string-to-be-truncated-and-much-text-here"
Enum.each(20..30, & string |> SlugHelper.slug(&1) |> IO.puts())

#⇒ another-long
#  another-long-string
#  another-long-string
#  another-long-string
#  another-long-string-to
#  another-long-string-to
#  another-long-string-to
#  another-long-string-to-be
#  another-long-string-to-be
#  another-long-string-to-be
#  another-long-string-to-be
```

Comment: I think there is a problem. I. e. `SlugHelper.slug("abc-def", 7) => "abc"` and `SlugHelper.slug("abc-def", 4) => ""`. Please, have a look at my solution also.