# Truncate text in Phoenix Framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a text field called content that I need to display an excerpt of.

What is the best way to do this?

Something like:

```
<% post.content.slice(0..50) %>
```

is what I have in mind; however, this gives me an argument error.

What is the best way to display the first 50 characters of the content text field?

Alternatively - could I create an excerpt field when the data is created/saved into the database?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `String.slice(post.content, 0..50)`, please check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/39395092/3102718

Comment: There is also a package that offers a truncate function and more: https://github.com/ikeikeikeike/phoenix_html_simplified_helpers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
defmodule MyApp.StringFormatter do

  def truncate(text, opts \\ []) do
    max_length  = opts[:max_length] || 50
    omission    = opts[:omission] || "..."

    cond do
      not String.valid?(text) -> 
        text
      String.length(text) < max_length -> 
        text
      true ->
        length_with_omission = max_length - String.length(omission)

        "#{String.slice(text, 0, length_with_omission)}#{omission}"
    end
  end
end
```

That's what I use in my app, I believe I shamelessly copy pasted it from somewhere but it works just fine and obviously you can modify it to your needs.

But if you dont need this fancy ommision thing then

```
String.slice(post.content, 0..50)
```

should work just fine

Comment: Note that `String.slice(text, 0..50)` will be the first 51 characters (zero-based). `String.slice(text, 0, 50)` will be the first 50 characters.